# GNUplot solid vertical lines in pdfcairo output

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, gnuplot

My Aqua terminal output shows solid lines where I want them: bottom border and x and y grids back.

When I change the output to pdfcairo, I cannot find a way to make the xgrid lines solid. Is this a known issue?

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 13.5,9.8 solid screen 0,.3 lt 1 lw 2
```

GNUplot 4.6.1
OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

If you want solid lines for the grid, I'd use a solid linetype for the grid, rather than relying on terminal settings:

```
set term pdfcairo size 13.5,9.8 solid
set output 'foo.pdf'
set grid lt 1 lc rgb 'black'
plot sin(x)
```

As a side note, my 
`pdfcairo` chokes on the `screen 0,.3` portion of your `set term` command.  I'm not sure what it's doing there, but I'm pretty sure that it's not what you want.